# How do I divide a circle into equal parts like a pie chart with Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cc-2014

Is there a fairly simple way to divide a circle into equal parts using Adobe Illustrator CC?

Answer (score 39):

**Polar Grid tool**... just tap the arrow keys while you drag. 
Up/Down for inner circles, left/right for diameter divisions.

[image: grid]

Or, <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>-click with the Polar Grid tool to set specific numbers of divisions.

Comment: Of course, you're stuck with the limitation of having all segments the same size.

Comment: Err.. question states..... "divide a circle into equal parts"

Comment: How do I divide it afterwards? I set it to 6 equal parts but using the Divide tool only makes two halfs of the circle.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus Swap the Stroke to a fill.. then it may divide properly.. or use the Live Paint Bucket Tool to Fill the individual areas with color, then Divide.

Answer (score 14):

Like plainclothes said ... an easy screenshot-walkthrough for an even number of segments:

1. Draw a circle
2. Add a line across
3. Rotate line/path with (TRICK!) the copy button N-times.
4. Repeat action (Command-D on OS X).
5. Select circle and all sections.
6. Use the pathfinder tool and select divide.
7. You got segments.

[image]

Comment: welcome to GD do you mind adding a little bit of explanation of each screenshot and possibly editing out all the unneeded panels so it would be easier for an un-experienced person to understand what you're doing

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot because I seem to be the only one who does not understand this. What is happening on point 3? What is "the copy button"?

Answer (score 12):

You can simply make a piechart with Illustrators own **chart-functionality**:

[image]

Fill in whatever % you want for the different slices, and then ungroup the whole thing afterwards, if you want to remove parts of it.

[image]

Comment: That would be the logical solution.

Comment: There are certainly other ways too, but i use this as it is extremely precise.

Comment: Fastest solution.

Answer (score 3):

1. Draw a path across the exact middle (horizontal or vertical)
2. Rotate and duplicate according to your needs to define the slices
3. Use the divide feature in the Pathfinder to split the circle up using your paths

Answer (score -1):

1. Draw a circle using the ellipse tool
2. Object -> Path -> Add Anchor Points
3. Repeat 2nd step as needed

Comment: Inserts 4, 8, 16, 32...etc anchor points. Doesn't generate slices as closed shapes, not useful if for ex.  one wants 5, 7 or 9 equal slices which together are the original circle.