# How can I create a polar (radial?) perspective grid in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective

I would like to create a perspective grid in Photoshop that would have the effect of looking through a cylinder. From searching online I *think* this is referred to as a 'polar' perspective grid.

I would like to render it with a 1 pixel width wire frame.

To clarify, I want to create a perspective grid similar to the image below but radial instead of rectangular. I hope that makes sense. I made the rectangular perspective grid below using `Filter > Vanishing point`.

[image]

So far I have tried to use the Vanishing point filter but from what I can tell it can only be used to make flat planes, I cant use it to make a radial plane. I'm wondering if I need to learn to use the 3D tools in Photoshop. I don't know how to use them currently or even if they are the best approach... I'm currently researching more about that approach.

I've seen online that Illustrator CS6 has a 'polar grid tool' which I could probably use, however I am in CS5, and ultimately I need the artwork in Photoshop...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply draw a series of repeated circles, each reduced in size. Then draw bisecting lines.

[image]

Photoshop CC screenshot, but it's pretty much the same for CS5.

If you have **Illustrator CS5** it's even easier using the **Polar Grid Tool** there : <kbd>**[See Here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27964/how-do-i-divide-a-circle-into-equal-parts-like-a-pie-chart-with-adobe-illustrato/27969#27969)**</kbd> Then just copy/paste to Photoshop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Scott. I was able to achieve the effect I wanted with the Polar Grid tool in Illustrator. Using the 'Concentric Dividers' > 'skew' control in the options panel allowed me to achieve the depth effect. Then I was able to render the polar grid as a png with no anti-aliasing to achieve the 1 pixel width lineart I needed. 

Thanks again for your advice!