# Segment circle into layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cc-2014

I want to divide a circle into 5 equal segments such that each segment will be on it's own layer. In general I want to create a loading animation that would consist of 5 images with number of visible segments increasing in each of them.

So far I've managed to draw a segmented circle following this question:
[How do I divide a circle into equal parts like a pie chart with Adobe Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27964/how-do-i-divide-a-circle-into-equal-parts-like-a-pie-chart-with-adobe-illustrato?newreg=85f030ea78374d71a99de88fc8121df3) but I have no idea how to split segments into layers.

Comment: Try making four new layers, and then cut and paste in front (`Ctrl/Cmd + F`) each segment in its own layer.

Comment: You could try `Release to Layers` in the **Layer Panel Menu.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic steps...

Create the divided circle with the **Polar Grid Tool**

Use the **Live Paint Bucket Tool** to fill the wedges (this turns the shapes into objects rather than a circle with lines through it)

Expand the Live Paint Group by clicking the `Expand` button on the **Control bar**

`Object > Ungroup` *several times* so that everything is ungrouped.

Then `Release to Layers` in the **Layers Panel Menu** to create a layer for each wedge.

[Here's an animation of this (1MB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzIHi.gif)
<sub>Purposefully not posted inline due to file size</sub>