# How do you create this concentric Circle pattern?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I came across this really cool concentric texture created on this image and wanted to recreate it. I have tried creating a brush preset to get this effect but that does not come out anywhere near as fine. Someone please help. How do I create this concentric circle pattern effect on the gradient?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Polar Grid Tool` in **Adobe Illustrator** to easily create this then copy/paste it to Photoshop. I don't think Photoshop has any direct, simple way of creating concentric circles.

[image]

Tap/hold the arrow keys *as you drag* to add rings (up/down arrows) or radius dividers (left/right arrows).

- Related: [How do I divide a circle into equal parts like a pie chart with Adobe Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/27969/3270)

In Photoshop, you would have to do a lot of duplicating and resizing.