# adding radial dividers to a polar grid

Tags: grids

Can I add radial dividers to a polar grid once it has been set. Is this possible. Seems like it should be but I can't figure it out.
Basically I have a pie chart with many radial divider and text in each. Need to add more.
Thanks

Comment: ermm.. what software?? [possibly helpful](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27964/how-do-i-divide-a-circle-into-equal-parts-like-a-pie-chart-with-adobe-illustrato/27969#27969) (if you are referring to Adobe Illustrator.)

Answer (score 0):

If it's in Illustrator and it has been made with the Polar Grid tool it's a group of 2 subgroups. Subgroup 1 contains the concentric circles, subgroup 2 contains the radial lines. You can access any mentioned item without ungrouping by selecting it in the layers panel. You need it if you want for example to split, move, rotate or recolorize one of the old radial lines. To insert a new line or circle you simply draw it.

I'm afraid there's no way to force the other items to move automatically when you insert a line or move something. To make such thing happen you should not use polar grid, but a pie chart and do it preferably in a flexible enough data visualization program.